# Why does using the scope resolution operator change which overloaded template in the global namespace gets called?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, overload-resolution

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class W, class T>
void foo(W& a, T& t)
{
  std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template <template <bool> class W, class T>
void foo(W<true>& a, const T& t)
{
  foo(a, const_cast<T&>(t));
}

template <class W>
void foo(W& a, int& t)
{
  std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

template <bool> struct what;
template<> struct what<true> { };

int main() {
  const int ci = 10;
  what<true> wt;

  foo(wt, ci);

  return 0;
}
```

The output is ([ideone link](https://ideone.com/jzEC5J)):

```
int
```

This makes sense to me: `foo(what<true>&, const int&)` matches the `const_cast` overload, which then calls `foo(what<true>&, int&)`, which matches the `int` overload.

Yet if I change the `const_cast` function to the following:

```
template <template <bool> class W, class T>
void foo(W<true>& a, const T& t)
{
    ::foo(a, const_cast<T&>(t));
}
```

The output is now ([ideone link](https://ideone.com/LYi7jK)):

```
generic
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Why does changing that `const_cast` overload of `foo` to call `::foo` cause the generic version to get called instead of the int version?

My understanding of `::` is that it was just to disambiguate which function to call in the case you have a method or a function in the global namespace. The `const_cast` overload still matches, which should then call `::foo(what<true>&, int&)`, which should match the `int` specialization - shouldn't it?

Further, if I change the order and place the `const_cast` overload using `::foo` after the `int` specialization, then the `int` specialization gets called ([ideone link](https://ideone.com/BWL3Ua)). Why does the order of definition matter here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names declared after the template can only be found via **argument-dependent name lookup**. Your overload of `foo` for `int&` is only found because one of the types involved, `W<true>`, is a specialization of a class template declared in the global namespace. Hence ADL looks for declarations in the global namespace in the instantiation context and finds the (more specialized), desired overload.

`::foo` is a qualified-id, which suppresses ADL, hence only names declared in the definition context are considered.